# How can i use "lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50]," in if else correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need define 2 different config line about datatable by if else but my lines not working. I need a hand.

```
 if(role === 1) {    
   lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50],  
 } else {      
    lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],  
 }
```

Comment: Try ternary operator: `lengthMenu: role === 1 ? [10, 25, 50] : [10, 25, 50, 75, 100]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't conditionally define in the middle of a JavaScript object definition, at least not with an `if` statement.

Generally you'll need to selectively modify it, or use a function.

For example, with a function:

```js
function lengthMenuForRole(role) {
  if (role === 1) {
    return [10, 25, 50];
  }

  return  [10, 25, 50, 75, 100];
}

obj = {
  ...,
  lengthMenu: lengthMenuForRole(role)
};
```

You could also have any given object `obj` and then:

```js
if(role === 1) {    
  obj.lengthMenu = [10, 25, 50];
} else {      
  obj.lengthMenu = [10, 25, 50, 75, 100];
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `obj.lengthMenu = [10, 25, 50],` should probably have a ; at the end rather than a ,

Comment: @BenStephens Fixed. Was a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let role = 1

let first_obj = {
    lengthMenu:(role ===1?[10, 25, 50]:[10, 25, 50, 75, 100])
}

console.log(first_obj)

role = 5

first_obj = {
    lengthMenu:(role ===1?[10, 25, 50]:[10, 25, 50, 75, 100])
}

console.log(first_obj)
```

Comment: lengthMenu: role == 1 ? [10, 25, 50] : role == 2 ? [10, 25, 50, 75, 100] : [10],

worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm assuming that the array is the same for each role except that the higher value options are being trimmed off (I'm not sure that Hao Wu's / Alan Omar's use of the ternary operator aren't easier to read than this though):

```js
const config = (role) => ({
  lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100].slice(0, role === 1 ? 3 : 5)
});

console.log(config(1));
console.log(config(2));
```